# Margens do elemento filho vazando para o elemento pai

Tags: html, css

não achei na comunidade algo que esclarecesse minha dúvida, então vamos lá!

No exemplo abaixo, não sei por que cargas d'água, a propriedade `margin` dos elementos `p` e `h1` excedem o limite do elemento pai.

```css
.div1 {
  background-color: cyan;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <p>paragrafo</p>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <h1>titulo</h1>
</div>
```

Analisando pelo inspetor visualizo está situação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por qual razão/motivo isto está acontecendo?

Por que a margem não se limita apenas dentro do elemento pai, assim aumentando sua altura?

Comment: margin-top em todos navegadores por algum motivo sai mesmo do elemento pai ou ate mesmo de elementos acima, eu sei que já li sobre isso em algum lugar, irei ver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme esta resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/2680515/1518921

**Conforme [*W3 Collapsing Margins*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins):**

> As margens adjacentes de duas ou mais caixas (que podem ou não ser irmãos) podem se combinar para formar uma única margem. Refere a este tipo de margens que se combinam deste modo como "colapso" e a margem combinada resultante é chamado de "margem de colapso".

Isto também é explicado https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting:

> Elementos com float, absolute e elementos com inline-block, table-cell, and table-captions por exemplo não são caixas de bloco realmente e caixas de bloco com overflow diferente de `overflow: visibile` geram um novo bloco para formatação do conteudo.
>
> No contexto de um bloco de formatação de conteúdo, as "caixas" são colocadas verticalmente fora uma após a outra, começando do topo do conteúdo de um bloco. A distancia vertical entre as caixas é determinada pela propriedade `margin`, as margens verticais entre o level dos blocos são adjacentes no na formatação do contexto causando o colapso.

Quando não ocorre o colapso (mesclamento das margens):

- Margens horizontais.
- Elementos com overflow que seja diferente de visible, como por exemplo hidden e auto
- Elementos com `float: left;` ou `float: right;`
- Elementos com `position` diferente de `static`

> **Nota:** Ainda pretendo melhorar a resposta, pois meu inglês é um pouco fraco e as vezes me perco no sentido da frase, fora que os links citados são outdate, estou vendo fontes mais atualizadas

### Como evitar o colapso

1. Para que a margem não afete o elemento pai você pode aplicar um `padding-top` (se usar `margin-top` no elemento filho) e `padding-bottom` (se usar `margin-bottom` no elemento filho) no elemento pai assim ele é corrigido automaticamente:

   ```css
   .pai1 {
       background: #f00;
       color: #fff;
   }

   .pai2 {
       padding: 1px 0; /* adiciona um px no topo e em baixo */
       margin: -1px 0; /* ajusta negativamente para que o padding aparente sumir */
       background: #00f;
       color: #fff;
   }

   .pai1 .filho, .pai2 .filho {
       margin: 20px 0;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <p>Teste</p>
   <!-- com o problema -->
   <div class="pai1">
       <div class="filho">teste</div>
   </div>

   <hr>

   <!-- sem o problema -->
   <div class="pai2">
       <div class="filho">teste</div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Usando o pseudo elemento `:before` e `:after`:

   ```css
   .pai {
       background: #f00;
       color: #fff;
   }

   .pai:before, .pai:after {
        content: " ";
        height: 0;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
   }

   .pai .filho {
       margin: 20px 0;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <p>Teste</p>
   <div class="pai">
       <div class="filho">teste</div>
   </div>
   ```
3. Usando `overflow: hidden;` (isto acaso não tenha altura fixa), este talvez seja a maneira mais simples de resolver:

   ```css
   .pai {
       background: #f00;
       color: #fff;
       overflow: hidden;
   }

   .pai .filho {
       margin: 20px 0;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <p>Teste</p>
   <div class="pai">
       <div class="filho">teste</div>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Cada navegador possui uma folha de estilos padrão, veja no seu inspector que o estilo está referenciando para `user agent stylesheet`.

Por exemplo, para o elemento `<h1></h1>`, no caso do chrome terá a seguinte regra:

```
h1 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Quando um elemento não possuir uma definição de css, sempre será usado o padrão do navegador, para ignorar, basta definir uma regra, veja:

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.div1 {
  background-color: cyan;
}
.div2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <p>paragrafo</p>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <h1>titulo</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Acho que ele tá perguntando da margem que vaza e não do estilo nativo que veem no webkit (que por sinal é possivel customizar no browser)

Comment: Correto @GuilhermeNascimento, gostaria de saber o motivo pelo qual a propriedade de margem vaza.