# Olá, tenho uma margem horizontal indesejada entre duas divs, gostaria de saber onde está o erro

Tags: html, css

```js
function typeWriter(elemento){

const textoArray = elemento.innerHTML.split('');
elemento.innerHTML = '';
textoArray.forEach((letra, i) => {
   setTimeout(() => elemento.innerHTML += letra, 75 * i);
});
}

const titulo = document.querySelector('.TxtDigi');
typeWriter(titulo);
```

```css
#parallax {
    /* a imagem usada */
    background-color: blue;

    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 650px; 

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect 
 filter: brightness(49%);*/
  
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.TxtDigi{
max-width:70%;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Courier new', courier, monospace;
font-size:3em;
color: white;
position: relative;
top: 6em;
left: 14%;
}
.TxtDigi::after{
content: '|';
opacity: 1;
animation: pisca .7s infinite;
}
@keyframes pisca {
0%, 100%{
opacity: 1;
 }
50%{
opacity:0;
 }

}

#Historia{

background-color: #104E8B;
height: 30em;


}
```

```html
<div id="parallax">
  
  <p class="TxtDigi">“Ligados um ao outro com a mesma ideia e Programando um roteiro para sua empresa”.</p>
    
</div>

<div class="Historia" style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">

</div>
```

**texto em negrito**

---

ah, e detalhe quando diminuo a tela a margem some: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando eu retiro a animação de texto digitado a margem some.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Os valores padrões de `p{[...]}` estão afetando na margin.

Redefina essa class no seu css:

```
.TxtDigi {
    max-width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Courier new', courier, monospace;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 6em;
    left: 14%;

    -webkit-margin-before: 0em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

Quando você tiver problemas como este você pode verificar no inspecionar elemento; geralmente abaixo de sua marcação css fica os valores padrões. Existem até alguns códigos que uso para reset dos valores padrões, um bom exemplo é antes de escrever meu código css colocar:

```
html,body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Isto ocorre porque o elemento `<P>` possui uma margem nativamente, essa margem vaza para fora do `<div>`, isso se chama colapso de margem

Conforme [**W3 Collapsing Margins**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> As margens adjacentes de duas ou mais caixas (que podem ou não ser irmãos) podem se combinar para formar uma única margem. Refere a este tipo de margens que se combinam deste modo como "colapso" e a margem combinada resultante é chamado de "margem de colapso".

Isto também é explicado https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting:

> Elementos com float, absolute e elementos com inline-block, table-cell, and table-captions por exemplo não são caixas de bloco realmente e caixas de bloco com overflow diferente de overflow: visibile geram um novo bloco para formatação do conteudo.
>
> No contexto de um bloco de formatação de conteúdo, as "caixas" são colocadas verticalmente fora uma após a outra, começando do topo do conteúdo de um bloco. A distancia vertical entre as caixas é determinada pela propriedade margin, as margens verticais entre o level dos blocos são adjacentes no na formatação do contexto causando o colapso.

**Quando não ocorre o colapso (mesclamento das margens):**

- Margens horizontais.
- Elementos com overflow que seja diferente de visible, como por exemplo hidden e auto
- Elementos com float: left; ou float: right;
- Elementos com position diferente de static

Como eu já expliquei nesta resposta:

- [Margens do elemento filho vazando para o elemento pai](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157085/3635)

---

as maneiras resolver são:

### overflow + altura dinamica:

Aqui aplicamos um overflow:hidden no paralax, assim a margem do "p" se limitar ao overflow.

```js
function typeWriter(elemento){

const textoArray = elemento.innerHTML.split('');
elemento.innerHTML = '';
textoArray.forEach((letra, i) => {
   setTimeout(() => elemento.innerHTML += letra, 75 * i);
});
}

const titulo = document.querySelector('.TxtDigi');
typeWriter(titulo);
```

```css
#parallax {
    overflow: hidden;

    /* a imagem usada */
    background-color: blue;

    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 650px; 

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect 
 filter: brightness(49%);*/
  
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.TxtDigi{
max-width:70%;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Courier new', courier, monospace;
font-size:3em;
color: white;
position: relative;
top: 6em;
left: 14%;
}
.TxtDigi::after{
content: '|';
opacity: 1;
animation: pisca .7s infinite;
}
@keyframes pisca {
0%, 100%{
opacity: 1;
 }
50%{
opacity:0;
 }

}

#Historia{

background-color: #104E8B;
height: 30em;


}
```

```html
<div id="parallax">
  
  <p class="TxtDigi">“Ligados um ao outro com a mesma ideia e Programando um roteiro para sua empresa”.</p>
    
</div>

<div class="Historia" style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">

</div>
```

### Aplicando padding

A outra solução é usar um padding de 1px em cima e outro abaixo, exemplo:

```js
function typeWriter(elemento){

const textoArray = elemento.innerHTML.split('');
elemento.innerHTML = '';
textoArray.forEach((letra, i) => {
   setTimeout(() => elemento.innerHTML += letra, 75 * i);
});
}

const titulo = document.querySelector('.TxtDigi');
typeWriter(titulo);
```

```css
#parallax {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;

    /* a imagem usada */
    background-color: blue;

    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 650px; 

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect 
 filter: brightness(49%);*/
  
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.TxtDigi{
max-width:70%;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Courier new', courier, monospace;
font-size:3em;
color: white;
position: relative;
top: 6em;
left: 14%;
}
.TxtDigi::after{
content: '|';
opacity: 1;
animation: pisca .7s infinite;
}
@keyframes pisca {
0%, 100%{
opacity: 1;
 }
50%{
opacity:0;
 }

}

#Historia{

background-color: #104E8B;
height: 30em;


}
```

```html
<div id="parallax">
  
  <p class="TxtDigi">“Ligados um ao outro com a mesma ideia e Programando um roteiro para sua empresa”.</p>
    
</div>

<div class="Historia" style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">

</div>
```

Você pode trocar:

```
padding-top: 1px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
```

Por

```
padding: 1px 0;
```

Que é equivalente, mas depende se não desejar controlar padding-left e padding-right