# COMO APLICAR UM BACKGROUND-COLOR NUM COMPONENT DO ANGULAR?

Tags: angular

Pretendo deixar o fundo preto da minha aplicação em angular. 
Inseri uma tag "body", ja que nao tem em angular, pra poder aplicar o estilo (body {background-color: black}). 
Porém fica com uma margem muito grande.

Há outra maneira de aplicar um background-color em angular?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <app-main></app-main>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
*margin{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Print:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só pra constar, existe sim a tag `<body>` em um projeto angular, ela fica na `index.html` e se quiser aplicar o estilo ao body, é só colocar no `style.css`

Comment: Inclusive testei aqui e funcionou

Answer (score 2):

A tag `<body>` existe sim em angular.

Quando você cria um projeto novo, dentro da pasta `src` são criados alguns arquivos:

[image: Estrutura de pastas]

E dentro do arquivo `index.html` voce vai encontrar o código base do html com a tag `<body>`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

inclusive dentro dela fica a tag `<app-root>` que é onde renderizam seus componentes

para alterar o css dessa pagina, é só adicionar no arquivo `styles.css`, que também é gerado na criação do projeto, o estilo do body que você já fez:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o resultado no template padrão do projeto Angular:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vou testar, muito obrigado pela informação!

Answer (score 1):

Isto esta errado:

```
*margin{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

O correto provavelmente seria isto `*`, que é o seletor global, assim:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Mas realmente não precisa tirar os espaçamentos de tudo, no caso bastaria apontar para HTML e BODY:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Ainda sim vale lembrar que outros elementos com margem podem afetar os elementos "pais", leia mais a respeito em:

- [Margens do elemento filho vazando para o elemento pai](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157069/3635)

Comment: Eu sinceramente nunca entendi mt bem a necessidade dessa implementação  (* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}), so uso como um costume que adquiri na faculdade kk